# Pure-FTPd do not login via mysql

Tags: mysql, configuration, ftp

I've got server on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. I need to install Pure-FTPd with MySQL authentication. 
I'm installed pure-FTPd by typing "apt-get install pure-ftpd-mysql". It was installed.
So, there's my "/etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftp.conf" file:

```
############################################################
#                                                          #
#         Configuration file for pure-ftpd wrappers        #
#                                                          #
############################################################

# If you want to run Pure-FTPd with this configuration   
# instead of command-line options, please run the
# following command :
#
# /usr/sbin/pure-config.pl /etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf
#
# Please don't forget to have a look at documentation at
# http://www.pureftpd.org/documentation.shtml for a complete list of
# options.

# Cage in every user in his home directory
ChrootEveryone              yes
# Turn on compatibility hacks for broken clients
BrokenClientsCompatibility  no
# Maximum number of simultaneous users
MaxClientsNumber            50
# Fork in background
Daemonize                   yes
# Maximum number of sim clients with the same IP address
MaxClientsPerIP             8
# If you want to log all client commands, set this to "yes".
# This directive can be duplicated to also log server responses.
VerboseLog                 yes 
# List dot-files even when the client doesn't send "-a".
DisplayDotFiles             no
# Don't allow authenticated users - have a public anonymous FTP only.
AnonymousOnly               no
# Disallow anonymous connections. Only allow authenticated users.
NoAnonymous                 yes
# Syslog facility (auth, authpriv, daemon, ftp, security, user, local*)
# The default facility is "ftp". "none" disables logging.
SyslogFacility              daemon
# Display fortune cookies
# FortunesFile              /usr/share/fortune/zippy
# Don't resolve host names in log files. Logs are less verbose, but 
# it uses less bandwidth. Set this to "yes" on very busy servers or
# if you don't have a working DNS.
DontResolve                 yes
# Maximum idle time in minutes (default = 15 minutes)
MaxIdleTime                 15
# MySQL configuration file (see README.MySQL)
MySQLConfigFile               /etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf
# 'ls' recursion limits. The first argument is the maximum number of
# files to be displayed. The second one is the max subdirectories depth
LimitRecursion             2000 8
# Are anonymous users allowed to create new directories ?
AnonymousCanCreateDirs      no
# If the system is more loaded than the following value,
# anonymous users aren't allowed to download.
MaxLoad                     4
# Port range for passive connections replies. - for firewalling.
PassivePortRange          50000:50100
# Disallow downloading of files owned by "ftp", ie.
# files that were uploaded but not validated by a local admin.
AntiWarez                   no
# File creation mask. <umask for files>:<umask for dirs> .
# 177:077 if you feel paranoid.
Umask                       133:022
# Minimum UID for an authenticated user to log in.
MinUID                      48
# Do not use the /etc/ftpusers file to disable accounts. We're already
# using MinUID to block users with uid < 500
UseFtpUsers no
# Allow FXP transfers for authenticated users.
AllowUserFXP                yes
# Allow anonymous FXP for anonymous and non-anonymous users.
AllowAnonymousFXP           no
# Users can't delete/write files beginning with a dot ('.')
# even if they own them. If TrustedGID is enabled, this group
# will have access to dot-files, though.
ProhibitDotFilesWrite       no
# Prohibit *reading* of files beginning with a dot (.history, .ssh...)
ProhibitDotFilesRead        no
# Never overwrite files. When a file whose name already exist is uploaded,
# it get automatically renamed to file.1, file.2, file.3, ...
AutoRename                  no
# Disallow anonymous users to upload new files (no = upload is allowed)
AnonymousCantUpload         yes
# Create an additional log file with transfers logged in a Apache-like format :
# fw.c9x.org - jedi [13/Dec/1975:19:36:39] "GET /ftp/linux.tar.bz2" 200 21809338
# This log file can then be processed by www traffic analyzers.
AltLog                     clf:/var/log/pureftpd.log
# Automatically create home directories if they are missing
CreateHomeDir               yes
# This option is useful with servers where anonymous upload is 
# allowed. As /var/ftp is in /var, it save some space and protect 
# the log files. When the partition is more that X percent full,
# new uploads are disallowed.
MaxDiskUsage               90
# Be 'customer proof' : workaround against common customer mistakes like
# 'chmod 0 public_html', that are valid, but that could cause ignorant
# customers to lock their files, and then keep your technical support busy
# with silly issues. If you're sure all your users have some basic Unix
# knowledge, this feature is useless. If you're a hosting service, enable it.
CustomerProof              yes
```

... and my "/etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf" file:

```
##############################################
#                                            #
# Sample Pure-FTPd Mysql configuration file. #
# See README.MySQL for explanations.         #
#                                            #
##############################################


# Optional : MySQL server name or IP. Don't define this for unix sockets.

# MYSQLServer     127.0.0.1


# Optional : MySQL port. Don't define this if a local unix socket is used.

# MYSQLPort       3306


# Optional : define the location of mysql.sock if the server runs on this host.

MYSQLSocket     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock


# Mandatory : user to bind the server as.

MYSQLUser       mybard_joo


# Mandatory : user password. You must have a password.

MYSQLPassword   bkmzyfevjd


# Mandatory : database to open.

MYSQLDatabase   mybard_joo


# Mandatory : how passwords are stored
# Valid values are : "cleartext", "crypt", "sha1", "md5" and "password"
# ("password" = MySQL password() function)
# You can also use "any" to try "crypt", "sha1", "md5" *and* "password"

MYSQLCrypt      md5


# In the following directives, parts of the strings are replaced at
# run-time before performing queries :
#
# \L is replaced by the login of the user trying to authenticate.
# \I is replaced by the IP address the user connected to.
# \P is replaced by the port number the user connected to.
# \R is replaced by the IP address the user connected from.
# \D is replaced by the remote IP address, as a long decimal number.
#
# Very complex queries can be performed using these substitution strings,
# especially for virtual hosting.


# Query to execute in order to fetch the password

#MYSQLGetPW      SELECT Password FROM users WHERE User='\L'
MYSQLGetPW  SELECT `ftp`.`passwd` AS `Password` FROM `bard__user_list` `u` INNER JOIN `bard__user_ftp` `ftp` ON `ftp`.`id_user`=`u`.`id` WHERE `u`.`login`='\L' AND `ftp`.`enabled`


# Query to execute in order to fetch the system user name or uid

#MYSQLGetUID     SELECT Uid FROM users WHERE User='\L'


# Optional : default UID - if set this overrides MYSQLGetUID

MYSQLDefaultUID 48


# Query to execute in order to fetch the system user group or gid

#MYSQLGetGID     SELECT Gid FROM users WHERE User='\L'


# Optional : default GID - if set this overrides MYSQLGetGID

MYSQLDefaultGID 502


# Query to execute in order to fetch the home directory

#MYSQLGetDir     SELECT Dir FROM users WHERE User='\L'
MYSQLGetDir SELECT CONCAT('/ftp/',`u`.`login`,'/') AS `Dir` FROM `bard__user_list` `u` INNER JOIN `bard__user_ftp` `ftp` ON `ftp`.`id_user`=`u`.`id` WHERE `login`='\L' AND `ftp`.`enabled`=1


# Optional : query to get the maximal number of files 
# Pure-FTPd must have been compiled with virtual quotas support.

# MySQLGetQTAFS  SELECT QuotaFiles FROM users WHERE User='\L'


# Optional : query to get the maximal disk usage (virtual quotas)
# The number should be in Megabytes.
# Pure-FTPd must have been compiled with virtual quotas support.

# MySQLGetQTASZ  SELECT QuotaSize FROM users WHERE User='\L'


# Optional : ratios. The server has to be compiled with ratio support.

# MySQLGetRatioUL SELECT ULRatio FROM users WHERE User='\L'
# MySQLGetRatioDL SELECT DLRatio FROM users WHERE User='\L'


# Optional : bandwidth throttling.
# The server has to be compiled with throttling support.
# Values are in KB/s .

# MySQLGetBandwidthUL SELECT ULBandwidth FROM users WHERE User='\L'
# MySQLGetBandwidthDL SELECT DLBandwidth FROM users WHERE User='\L'

# Enable ~ expansion. NEVER ENABLE THIS BLINDLY UNLESS :
# 1) You know what you are doing.
# 2) Real and virtual users match.

# MySQLForceTildeExpansion 1


# If you're using a transactionnal storage engine, you can enable SQL
# transactions to avoid races. Leave this commented if you are using the
# traditionnal MyIsam engine.

# MySQLTransactions On
```

Everything seems to be great, buy when I'm trying to login, it's exit with an error: "Server said: Login authentication failed".
I've restarted server several times, but it doesn't work... It seems it doesn't apply config files.

I've tried this command: "/usr/sbin/pure-config.pl /etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf", but it still not working: "/usr/sbin/pure-config.pl: No such file or directory".

I've got only three files in "/etc/pure-ftpd/conf": ChrootEveryone, CreateHomeDir, MySQLConfigFile. Everything seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, guys, everything is OK now. Don't now how, but in mysql.conf file MYSQLCrypt was set as cleartext... Now, when I set it to md5 back everethin seems to be grate!

Comment: I too had same issue., changing to clear text did work.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason can be that the `pure-ftpd-mysql package` is not installed at all. Ok, you said you installed it. But I found just now that I did not have it installed, only its config files which were created by ISPConfig during its setup.

So, installing the package fixed the issue immediately for me:

```
apt-get install pure-ftpd-mysql
```

For more detailed explanations and other possible reasons, refer to my blog post about this: "[How to fix '530 Login authentication failed' for ISPConfig FTP logins?](http://ma.juii.net/blog/fix-ispconfig-ftp-logins)".